# Relationship between the parameters of the Normal distribution and parameters in the probit with multiple predictors?

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, generalized-linear-model, interpretation, probit

According to A. Agresti (2007, p. 73) in binary probit regression: "The parameters of the normal distribution relate to the parameters in the probit by mean (mu = -alpha/beta) and standard deviation (sigma = 1/beta)". E.g.:

```
       z.score = probit (p) = alpha + beta * x
       mu = -alpha / beta
       sigma = 1/abs(beta)
```

I wanted to ask an advice on how to find the relationship between both parameters of the Normal distribution and the parameters of the probit when facing  two predictors (and interaction between them). Suppose x and k are continuous and nominal predictors, respectively:

```
      probit (p) = alpha + beta(1) * x + beta(2) * k + beta(3) * k * x
```

Many thanks!